# Why my Lenovo X270's charger type c won't charge my phone?

Tags: usb-3.1-type-c

I have a Jesy J9S phone, and a Lenovo X270, both with USB Type C connectors.

When I plug in the Lenovo charger into my phone, it does not start charging, but the charger works in the laptop.

Why is this? Does the charger have some "intelligence" to know that it is not the laptop the one connected?

Comment: Does your hardware support USB 3.1 GEN 1 or USB 3.1 GEN 2?  Are you using the appropriate cable?

Comment: Hello @Ramhound, I don't know. I only know that the charger says this output: `20V 2.25A, 15V 3A, 9V 2A, 5V 2A`

Comment: I am not asking about the laptop's charger.  I am asking about the USB 3.1 cable and the USB 3.1 capabilities of the laptop.  Do the proper amount of research, then edit, your question.